# how to perform statistics for every n elements in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

How to perform basic statistics for every n elements in Mongodb. For example, if I have total of 100 records like below

| Name | Count | Sample |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | x |
| a | 20 | y |
| a | 10 | z |
| b | 10 | x |
| b | 10 | y |
| b | 5 | z |

how do I perform mean, median, std dev for every 10 records so I get 10 results. So I want to calculate mean/median/std dev for A for every 10 sample till all the elements of database. Similarly for b, c and so on

excuse me if it is a naive question

Answer (score 1):

you need to have some sort of counter to keep track of count.... for example I have added here rownumber then applied bucket of 3 (here n=3) and then returning the sum and average of the group(3). this example can be modified to do  some sorting and grouping before we create the bucket to get the desired result.

Pls refer to https://mongoplayground.net/p/CL7vQGUWD_S

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "rownum": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function() {try {row_number+= 1;} catch (e) {row_number= 0;}return row_number;}",
          "args": [],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $bucket: {
      groupBy: "$rownum",
      // Field to group by
      boundaries: [
        1,
        4,
        7,
        11,
        14,
        17,
        21,
        25
      ],
      // Boundaries for the buckets
      default: "Other",
      // Bucket id for documents which do not fall into a bucket
      output: {
        // Output for each bucket
        "countSUM": {
          $sum: "$count"
        },
        "averagePrice": {
          $avg: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```